# Sending an attach document via swiftmailer

Tags: symfony, pdf, attachment, xls, swiftmailer

I am trying to attach a file to an email.

First i create the file using snappyBundle for pdf && an xsl file using liugioBundle.

Right after that i need to send it as attach document in email using swiftmailer.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the ->attach() method on your Switft_Mailer object

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

```
$email = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Subject')
    ->setFrom('me@domain.com')
    ->setTo($recipients)
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'Emails/niceEmail.html.twig',
            compact('foo', 'bar', 'message')
        ),
        'text/html'
    )
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'));
```